# Как защитить от клонирования при unserialize Объекта PHP

Tags: php, unserialize

Собственно проблема.

Есть простой класс в который мы передаем базовый объект в конструктор.

```
class Lite{
    protected $Core;

    public function __construct($Core){
        $this->Core = $Core;
    }

}
```

Потом делаем serialize, и при следующих запросах страницы unserialize.

Проблема в том, что используется

```
spl_autoload_register(function($Class){
     .....
});
```

И после вызова unserialize, $this->Core это уже не ссылка на объект, это уже полностью самостоятельный блин объект. Есть идеи как это обойти? Смотрел в сторону singleton, но в таком случае придется полностью переделывать конструктор.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что за "самостоятельный блин объект" чем он отличается от "ссылки на объект"?

Или проблема в том, что вы не можете сериализоавть closure(замыкание)?

Comment: closure не поддаются сереализации, об этом сказано в документации. Проблема в том, что после unserialize мы получаем полностью автономные объекты. Тоисть свои поля и все такое, ну и конечно же память. Хотя сереализацию мы делали с сылками на объект.

Comment: `class Lite implement Serializable { ... }` и в методах `serialize()`/`unserialize()` пишите свою логику.

Answer (score 1):

А так не получится?

```
spl_autoload_register(array($this, '$Class');
```

Comment: Shrek, а $this это чего? И где у нас тогда сама функция ?

Comment: что ты вообще пытаешься сделать?

**spl_autoload_register** обычно суют для autoload чтобы не писать везде **include** вопрос, зачем тогда туда, да даже там писать функцию, в которую ты передаешь **protected $Core;**

Comment: Мне кажется я уже понял в чем дело. Если получится выложу сюда весь код покажу.